# Specify SSH private key for Ansible host added dynamically via add_host task

Tags: ansible

I am using the `ansible.builtin.add_host` task module to add a new host to the in-memory inventory of Ansible Playbook. However, I don't see a way to specify which SSH private key should be associated with the newly added host.

**Question**: How can I associate an SSH private key path to an Ansible host that's added via `add_host`?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should move it to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I associate an SSH private key path to an Ansible host that's added via `add_host`?

Exactly as you do with any other host you add to your [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html): you set the expected variable `ansible_private_key_file` for that host.

[`add_host` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html) specifies you can set any variable in the module while adding your host. You can find the reference to the `ansible_private_key_file` config variable in the [config appendix](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html)

*Note: `ansible_private_key_file` was previously known as `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` and is still aliased. Meanwhile you should avoid using that old name in case it gets removed*

So in a nutshell:

```yaml
- name: Add host to inventory wiht ssh priv key
  ansible.builtin.add_host:
    name: somehost
    ansible_private_key_file: /path/to/priv.key
```